# Python script: wait until job in tmux session has completed

Tags: scripting, python, tmux

I am trying to continuously run a python script with random parameters from another python script, where each run is in its own tmux session. A very simplified overview of what I'm trying to do goes like this:

```
# Python script to run other python scripts
from subprocess import call
import random

while True
    param = randint(1,100)
    runmyscript ="tmux send-keys -t mysession"+str(param)+" 'python myscript.py param' "
    call(runmyscript)
    #Wait until myscript.py is done running in its tmux session <-- How to do that?
```

For example, let's say that the random numbers are 57, 61, 88 ... etc. The above script should run:

- 'myscript.py 57' in a tmux session called "mysession57"
- 'myscript.py 61' in a tmux session called "mysession61"
- 'myscript.py 88' in a tmux session called "mysession88"
  ... etc

But how can I make sure that the script waits until each script in its tmux session is finished?

Comment: Not an answer, and I don't know tmux but... there must be a better way, a more programmatic way, of doing what you need to do than simulating keypresses in a command window to run a script (because that's what I assume `tmux send-keys` does). Anything that remotely resembles directly invoking some kind of command instead of simulating keypresses would have a better chance of providing you with a method of notifying the caller when it's done.

Comment: You're 100% right. But I have reached the point that I must run what I have and get my results asap. That said, I'm sure that the question could be rephrased so that it refers to the same concept but less sloppy..

Comment: Are you using tmux for parallelization? Don't. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/python-how-can-i-run-python-functions-in-parallel

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import call
import random

while True:
    param = random.randint(1,100) #add random first or from random import randint
    runmyscript ="tmux send-keys -t mysession %s 'python myscript.py param' "%str(parma)
    call(runmyscript,shell=True)#you should add if or something to break loop
```